# TYPO3 Domain repository temporarily change settings

Tags: typo3, repository, settings, findall, domain-model

Normally if someone wants to run the function `findAll()`, he/she has to define the persistence Pid to let TYPO3 know where to look. If the persistence pid is not present, a function in the repository would do the trick. Like the following:

```
 public function initializeObject() {
    $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get(Typo3QuerySettings::class);
    $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
    $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
 }
```

But what happens if we do not have access to the repository? I mean the repository belongs to another extension and you can not edit it. The solution would be to extend the repository to an **extend** extension but this is sometimes too much to create an extended version only for that.

The question here is:

**How do i temporarily, just for this request, change the settings of the repository, in this case change the `setRespectStoragePage` to `false`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some coding i finally figured it out.

**Step 1.**

create a protected variable where you wanna use the repository request:

```
/**
* @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QuerySettingsInterface
*/
protected $querySettings;
```

**Step 2.**

Inject the `QuerySettingsInterface` in your current PHP class. If you want to use that in your controller, then you could do something like that:

```
public function __construct()
{
   parent::__contruct();
   $this->querySettings = $this->objectManager->get(QuerySettingsInterface::class);
}
```

otherwise

```
public function __construct()
{
    $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
    $this->querySettings = $objectManager->get(QuerySettingsInterface::class);
}
```

**Step 3**

Finally you can set the settings like that:

```
$this->querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
$this->contactRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($this->querySettings);
$contacts = $this->contactRepository->findAll();
```

Simple and no extended extension needed just to implement the function in the repository.

Best regards